# Character from downloaded AssetBundle renders as magenta in Unity

Tags: unity, assets, asset-management

I'm currently using Unity 5.3.5f1 free edition.

I have a character in an assetbundle that I load from my server at runtime. The target platform for the asset bundle is Android. The default shader that I use for all the materials in the character is `Mobile/Diffuse`.

My problem is that when I download and instantiate the character, the whole character appears solid magenta. Please see the below screenshot:

[image: solid magenta character]

Interestingly, if I open the scene window and switch the shader to something else (anything) the material starts to display correctly even when I switch it back to `Mobile/Diffuse`. Obviously, doing this in game isn't a choice so what causes this behavior and how can I fix this? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

This issue only happens when using a mobile shader. When I shifted to the Standard shader, this issue disappeared. Perhaps this is a bug in Unity.

So if you're having a similar problem, just shift to the Standard shader if possible.